# Peformance of Amazon EC2, what do I actually get?

Tags: performance, amazon-ec2, cloud-computing

I have read some articles about Amazon's Web Services and am interested in:

1. Knowing exactly what I am getting (maybe some equivalent terms to a physical machine would be helpful)
2. The "performance" compared to I guess my own machine or other widely available options.

That being said, I have an intel i7 processor with 8 cores, 2GB of RAM per core. I also do not know much about hardware, distributed computing and parallel computation.

I will be working with large datasets and applying algorithms to these large datasets. Anyway, here are the two articles I read which address these questions: [Article1](http://blog.carlmercier.com/2012/01/05/ec2-is-basically-one-big-ripoff/) and [Article2](http://gevaperry.typepad.com/main/2009/03/figuring-out-the-roi-of-infrastructureasaservice.html).

I do not really know all the terms in the articles but it seems that the best I can get is not much better than my own machine. The simplest test I did (which greatly disappointed me) was to start an instance on EC2, run python and create a large barabasi graph via networkx (a graph library). I forget the actual size but my machine completed the task in about a minute, while EC2 had to shut the process down. So much for high performance computing...

It is also likely that I am missing the big idea in my usage or thoughts about Amazon EC2. Please let me know and thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** To clarify I am interested in computing power. Will I be able to process my large datasets more effectively (in less time)?

Comment: What problem do you think EC2 is suppose to solve exactly?  You are trying to compare your home computer to virtual hardware which is an unfair comparison

Comment: For one EC2 gives you computing power **without** the need to buy hardware, maintain hardware, arrange a server room with cooling. You can also access it from anywhere. None of these are about calculating power pur sang, but those parts are important.

Comment: Checkout my edit. I am solely interested in computing performance. Will I be able to process my large datasets more effectively (faster)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amazon clearly states on [their EC2 Page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) and their [Instance Types Page](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) what the stats of each machine is.

For example the free tier you likely tried out and was not impressed with the performance with is a "micro instance"

> **Micro Instance** 613 MiB of memory, up to 2 ECUs (for short periodic bursts), EBS storage only, 32-bit or 64-bit platform

Now there is one translation we need to do ECUs to actual processing power

> EC2 Compute Unit (ECU) – One EC2 Compute Unit (ECU) provides the equivalent CPU capacity of a 1.0-1.2 GHz 2007 Opteron or 2007 Xeon processor.

So the machine you tested it on was a computer with 2.0-2.4 GHz (but only for short periodic bursts) **that only had 613 MiB of RAM**.

The ram is likely the thing that killed your performance. Your machine had triple the ram the EC2 machine did and had 8 cores (and likely running faster than the bursting speed of the EC2 instance) compared to the EC2 machines 1 core.

---

Now compare this to the "High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large Instance"

> **High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large Instance** 68.4 GiB of memory, 26 EC2 Compute Units (8 virtual cores with 3.25 EC2 Compute Units each), 1690 GB of local instance storage, 64-bit platform

So now we have a machine that has 68.4 gigs of RAM compared to your 8, and has 8 cores (same as you) and running at 3.25 to 3.9 Ghz.

This machine will likely beat your machine doing the same task.

---

Now, why use EC2? What if you wanted to run 20 copies of your test at the same time, at home you would need to buy 19 more machines (lets say $1000 per machine), so **you would need to spend $19000 now and when you are done you have servers you don't need any more not doing anything at all.**

By using EC2, you could *rent* 20 servers and only pay for 1 hour of usage. At $1.00 per hour rate for the High-Memory Quadruple Extra Large Instance **it would only cost you $20**.

Comment: Yes I tried the Ubuntu free tier.